# Justification for approaching limit from any direction

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, continuity

I want to see a rigorous explanation why the following general fact:
$$ f \text{ continuous at z} \Longleftrightarrow \left( \forall (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} : \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = z \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = f(z)  \right) ,$$
implies that we can "approach the limit from any direction" in the case of functions $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$. Specifically, I want to see why the following equivalence (last two equalities) holds:
$$ f'(z) := \lim_{\substack{h \to 0 \\ h \in \mathbb{C}}} \left( \frac{f(z + h) - f(z)}{h} \right) = \lim_{\substack{h \to 0 \\ h \in \mathbb{R}}} \left( \frac{f(z + h) - f(z)}{h} \right) = \lim_{\substack{h \to 0 \\ h \in \mathbb{R}}} \left( \frac{f(z + ih) - f(z)}{ih} \right) .$$

Moreover, why should the last equality above imply that the limit is the same from all the infinitely-many other directions $z$ can be approached from (i.e., why is the Cauchy-Riemann criterion sufficient for defining differentiability)?

Answer (score 2):

They’re not equivalent. The correct statement is if the first limit exists, then it is equal to the other two. Merely having Cauchy-Riemann being satisfied at a point is not enough to conclude differentiability at that point. Here’s a very obvious counterexample: define $f:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$ such that $f(z)=0$ whenever $z$ lies on one of the coordinate axes, and define $f(z)$ in any willy-wonka fashion away from the axes (actually we don’t even need to get too crazy… just define $f=1$ away from the coordinate axes). Then, computing the last two limits in question at $z=0$ gives $0$, but the first limit doesn’t even exist. Heck, $f$ isn’t even continuous at the origin.

The correct equivalence between complex differentiability and Cauchy-Riemann have been discussed several times on this site. See for example [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3696425/568204), and the various linked related answers for more context (with slightly different hypotheses to get slightly different conclusions).

Comment: Thank you for answering (refuting) my second question. Revising my first question, given that the derivative $f'(z)$ exists, I still don't see why the two other limits are equal (intuitively, yes they are "approaching horizontally and vertically", but I can't deduce this rigorously from the first fact in my post).

Comment: @AbcedDecba it follows directly from what you wrote. I’m not sure what more to explain. If you want, it’s atheorem of composition of limits.

Comment: in fact even more directly, if you just write out the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition for limits, you'll see that the $\delta$ which 'works' for the first limit 'works' for the other same. This is the most direct and rigorous, and fastest proof there is.