# Question About two sided directional derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Question: Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(0,0)=0$ and for $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$:

$f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$.

Show that the two-sided directional derivative of $f$ evaluated at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ exists in all directions $h\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$, but that $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

I am unsure how to solve this problem. I believe I need to set up a limit as $h\to0$, but behind that I am stumped.

Comment: Do you know the definition of directional derivatives? Do you know the definition of differentiability of a multivariable function? See this related question for an example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372070/f-not-differentiable-at-0-0-but-all-directional-derivatives-exist?rq=1

Comment: If you learn the theorem stated in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3339076/568204 then this question becomes almost trivial.

Comment: $f$ is discontinuous at $(0,0)$ no matter what value you assign to $f(0,0) . $

Comment: So, I checked the other question out, but it is still confusing. I kinda get that i need to use a limit, but overall I have no idea what vector coordinates are needed, if they are even needed at all. More over, the frechet derivative is not something I learned.

Comment: You asked the same question three hours earlier at [Question on two sided directional derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3696310/question-on-two-sided-directional-derivatives). Please don't do that; it wastes the site's resources. Also, please don't use generic terms like "question" in the title. All posts on this site are questions – imagine how the main page would look and how inefficient it would be if everyone did that.

Comment: I don’t know exactly what the definition of the directional derivative is, let alone a two sided. Do I maybe need to develop a hessian matrix?

Comment: Pardon me @joriki, I took down the other post in order to avoid further issues. I am still new to this site, so I will take note for the future.

Comment: I shall do so posthaste

Comment: @joriki are you able to assist me further with this problem?

Comment: @Tony456, the directional derivative of $f$ in $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to a direction $h\in\mathbb{R}^2$ is the limit $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x+th)-f(x)}{t}$. In other words, it is the derivative of the function $f(x+th)$ at $t=0$.

Comment: @Tony456, in the other hand we say $f$ is differentiable at $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ iff there is a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim\limits_{v\to 0}\frac{f(x+v)-f(x)-L(v)}{|v|}=0$.

Comment: With these definitions in mind, can you understand now the solution of the related question?

Comment: I think I do understand it.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use polar coordinates to write the function as

$$
f(r,\phi)=r\cos\phi\sin\phi=\frac12r\sin2\phi\;.
$$

Since $\sin(2(\phi+\pi))=\sin2\phi$, the angular factor is the same for opposite directions, so along any line through the origin the function behaves like an absolute value; e.g., on $(x,y)=(\lambda,\lambda)$ it takes the form $\frac1{\sqrt2}|\lambda|$. The absolute value function is not differentiable at $0$, so the two-sided directional derivatives don’t exist.

Comment: Is it still possible to solve this via a limit? I kinda wanna see how one would go about doing that.

Comment: @Tony456: Perhaps you could first say something about the discrepancy with the problem statement? It asks to prove that the two-sided directional derivatives exist, but it seems that they don't (unless I've made a mistake). What's the source of the problem?

Comment: The source of the problem is from a math textbook published by a Dr. Sundraman. Let me check the problem from the textbook and I will get back to you.